# How can I get OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware to validate the signing certificate validity dates?

Tags: openid-connect, katana, adal, identityserver3

I am using Microsoft's `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware` against IdentityServer3 in a hybrid flow.  I'll skip the IdentityServer3 setup code (as I don't think there's an issue there), but here's the relying party startup code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
});

var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "https://localhost:44300/",
    ClientId = "hybridclient",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44301/",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    Scope = "openid profile"
};

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

I've noticed that when IdentityServer3 is using an expired certificate for signing--which it allows, but dutifully logs as a warning--the expiration on the certificate is ignored and the authentication is permitted.  This seems wrong.

I don't know whose responsibility this would be (`OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware`? ADAL?) as it seems to me to be an easy authentication failure when the signing cert is expired.  I've looked at the code all the way down through Katana to the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` in ADAL and I can't see that the expiration is checked.

I can roll something myself, either in the `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeyResolver` or the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification on `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`, but it seems like this should be something built-in.

Is there a way to have the Microsoft OIDC middleware validate the signing cert expiration?  Or am I missing something?

**Update**: Given Brent's answer, this is apparently a [gap in the functionality of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` that Microsoft would like to fill](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/329).  I can only say I see this currently, with v4.0.0 installed (as its a dependency of the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` NuGet package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need derive from JwtSecurityTokenHandler, override ValidateIssuerSecurityKey and check the signature. OpenIdConnectOptions.SecurityTokenHandlers can be used to set the handler.

When fixed, this will be easier.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/329

Comment: I figured something similar.  Thanks for the confirmation!  I'll update my question to highlight the specific version to which this applies.